# Concatenating records when id is the same in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11 G database.

My table CHATUSERS looks like this:

```
UserId    - Identifier
SeqNum    - Order of chat conversation
ChatText  - Chat Text
DateAdded - DateTime Chat conversation happened.
```

An user can have multiple chat sessions in a day.
I want to combine all the ChatText per person per day.

Example:

```
UserId SeqNum DateAdded ChatText 
--------------------------------
1      1      28-OCT-14 Hey, How are You?
1      2      28-OCT-14 Do you have a minute?
1      3      28-OCT-14 Wanted to talk to you about something.
1      1      25-OCT-14 Congratulations!
1      2      25-OCT-14 on your promotion
```

So the SELECT query would return results as:

```
UserId, DateAdded and CompleteText
1  28-OCT-14 Hey, How are You? Do you have a minute? Wanted to talk to you about something.
1  25-OCT-14 Congratulations! on your promotion
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You should look into LISTAGG().

Comment: Which 11g version exactly? If you are on 11gR2, you can look into `LISTAGG`, if it is 11gR1 the answer will be different.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Then `LISTAGG` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid, dateadded, listagg(chattext, ' ') within group (order by seqnum) 
from chatusers
group by userid, dateadded;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `11gR2`,  you could use `LISTAGG`.

```
SELECT UserId, 
                DateAdded, 
                LISTAGG(ChatText, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ChatText) AS CompleteText
FROM  ChatUsers
GROUP BY UserId, DateAdded;
```

For other alternatives, have a look at http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php